# Confused with Backbone.js Paginator

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, pagination, underscore.js

I am trying to introduce pagination using the [backbone.js paginator plugin](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator)'s `requestPager`.

**Problem:** After setting up the `collection` which extends `Backbone.Paginator.requestPager`, I refreshed the webpage and the javascript console threw the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a){return new m(a)} has no method 'result' backbone.paginator.js:678`

I am very new to backbone and is not sure what went wrong. Is it because I used `fetch()`, which showed up in the screenshot of the error below? I also noticed that no `GET` requests were sent to the backend. What happened, and how should I fix this? Thanks!

**JS code**

```
// Collection

window.ListingCollection = Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.extend({
    model: Listing,

    paginator_core: {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'api/listings'
    },

    paginator_ui: {
        firstPage: 0,
        currentPage: 0,
        perPage: 10,
        totalPages: 10
    },

    server_api: {
        '$filter': '',
        '$per_page': function() { return this.perPage; },
        '$current_row': function() { return this.currentPage * this.perPage; },
        '$order_by': 'listing_id'
    },

    parse: function(response){
        this.totalPages = Math.floor(response.total_rows / this.perPage);
    }

});
```

**JS Code**

```
// Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'listings',
        'listings': 'listings'
    },

    listings: function() {
        var self = this;

        // Load initial search results
        this.listingList = new ListingCollection();
        this.listingList.fetch({
            success: function() {
                self.listingListView = new ListingListView({ model: self.listingList });
                $('#listing_list table').append(self.listingListView.render().el);
            }
        });
        this.listingFilterView = new ListingFilterView();
    }
});
```

**Screenshot of Error in Javascript Console**
[image]

[image]

**JS Includes**

```
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/js/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/backbone.paginator.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using older version of Underscore. I use 1.3.1 and it does not have `result()` method. Download their new production [version 1.3.3](http://underscorejs.org/#) - it has `result()`.

Comment: Great! I updated to 1.3.3 and that error goes away! Now I get an error with the `_.template` function, it does not seem to like `<% if(<%= address_2 %>){%>, <%= address_2 %><%}%>` anymore!

Comment: What template engine do you use? Syntax looks somewhat confusing... I use Handlebars and it's awesome.

Comment: I use the default template engine that comes with backbone.js/underscore.js. I will look into Handlebars, thanks!!

Comment: Gotcha. Never used it, sorry. In any case, in Handlebars this template would look like this: {{#if address_2}}, {{address_2}}{{/if}}. Pretty neat.

Comment: I don't know the correct syntax but I would try this: `<% if (address_2) {%>, <%= address_2 %><% } %>`. I mean, don't use `<%= %>` inside a *scriptlet*